# Multiple plot by group by one function

Tags: r, plot, scatter-plot

I have the following data:

```
Animal  MY  Age
1   17.03672067 1
1   17.00833641 2
1   16.97995215 3
1   16.95156788 4
1   16.92318362 5
1   16.88157748 6
2   16.83997133 2
2   16.79836519 3
2   16.75675905 4
2   16.7151529  5
2   16.67354676 6
2   16.63194062 7
3   16.59033447 1
3   16.54872833 2
3   16.50712219 3
3   16.46551604 4
3   16.4239099  5
3   16.38230376 6
4   16.34069761 1
4   16.29909147 2
4   16.25748533 3
4   16.21587918 4
4   16.17427304 5
4   16.1326669  6
```

I want to plot a scatter plot between MY vs Age for each animal. I use this function

```
  plot(memo$MY[memo$Animal=="1223100747"]~memo$Age[memo$Animal=="1223100747"]).
```

If I now want to add a same plot (MY vs Age) for another animals, I just need to use function: `lines`. 
However, since I have about 200 animals I do not want to do this manually 100 times. My questions is that: How can I plot these different animals by one function?, instead of using `lines`, `lines` ....`lines`)

Regards,
Phuong

Answer (score 0):

You can use `by` for example :

```
by(memo,memo$Animal,FUN=function(x) plot(x$MY~x$Age))
```

Comment: hi agstudy: my data contain missing value. How can I specify this using you suggestion? Another question is: Is that possible to classify animal by another factor such as stage, i.e. each animal has stage 1,2,3. So I want to plot animals in stage 1, then stage 2, then sateg 3? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a loop or a matplot if you want to use base R, but I advise you to use package ggplot2.

```
DF <- read.table(text="Animal  MY  Age
1   17.03672067 1
1   17.00833641 2
1   16.97995215 3
1   16.95156788 4
1   16.92318362 5
1   16.88157748 6
2   16.83997133 2
2   16.79836519 3
2   16.75675905 4
2   16.7151529  5
2   16.67354676 6
2   16.63194062 7
3   16.59033447 1
3   16.54872833 2
3   16.50712219 3
3   16.46551604 4
3   16.4239099  5
3   16.38230376 6
4   16.34069761 1
4   16.29909147 2
4   16.25748533 3
4   16.21587918 4
4   16.17427304 5
4   16.1326669  6",header=TRUE)

library(ggplot2)
DF$Animal <- factor(DF$Animal)

p1 <- ggplot(DF,aes(x=MY,y=Age,colour=Animal)) + geom_line()
print(p1)
```

Comment: hi Roland, I tried your suggestion with ggplot2. It works perfectly as I expected.
However, if I now want to select only animals in stage 1 to plot. It means I have another factors which is "stage= 1,2,3" to control. How can I specify this?

Comment: Well, you can subset your data.frame or you can facet the plot, which is probably what you want to do. Google for "ggplot2 facet".

Comment: hi Roland. I used subset data. Well, it for the time being satisfies me. Thanks alot!